# Spark-submit "ClassNotFound" Exception

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run the wordcount java program by using spark-submit but got a "ClassNotFound" Exception.
My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import scala.Tuple2;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;


public class JavaWordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create Spark context with Spark configuration
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count"));
        sc.addJar("/Users/fwy/IdeaProjects/wordcount-spark/target/wordcount-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar");

        /*JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("/home/ericfang1216/shakespeare_basket");*/
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("/Users/fwy/shakespeare-basket1");
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = textFile
                .flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator())
                .mapToPair(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))
                .reduceByKey((a, b) -> a + b);
        /*counts.saveAsTextFile("/home/ericfang1216/shakespeareOutput");*/
        counts.saveAsTextFile("/Users/fwy/shakespeareOutput");
    }
}
```

And my spark-submit command is:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit \
--master local[4] \
--class ​JavaWordCount \
/Users/fwy/IdeaProjects/wordcount-spark/target/wordcount-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Can anyone please help?

The error message as follows:

```
21/03/23 15:40:35 WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load ​JavaWordCount.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ​JavaWordCount
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVrZq.png)

The Project tree are as follows:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── log4j.properties
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── JavaWordCount.java
│   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │       └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       └── java
└── wordcount-spark.iml
```

Step debug as @Yu Xiang suggested:

```
(base) $:~ fwy$ java -jar /Users/fwy/IdeaProjects/wordcount-spark/target/wordcount-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Hello
```

Run the javap -cp command

```
(base) $:~ fwy$ javap  -cp /Users/fwy/IdeaProjects/wordcount-spark/target/wordcount-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar JavaWordCount
Compiled from "JavaWordCount.java"
public class JavaWordCount {
  public JavaWordCount();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Structure of the JAR:

```
├── JavaWordCount.class
└── META-INF
    ├── MANIFEST.MF
    └── maven
        └── cn.fwy
            └── wordcount-spark
                ├── pom.properties
                └── pom.xml
```

I solved this problem by adding `<mainClass>JavaWordCount</mainClass>` in my pom.xml.
And then at the spark-submit command, I did not provide the `--class` statement. The jar completed successfully.
But I still can not find out the reason for the previous error.

Comment: Which class is giving you the error? could you add the error to the question?

Comment: WARN SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load ​JavaWordCount.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ​JavaWordCount

Comment: What is the package of the class JavaWordCount? You may be missing it in the command line args.

Comment: I don't think I set any package for the class JavaWordCount. You may review my project structure above.

Comment: Packages in Java are implemented through directory structure. So everything under src/main/java will be part of the package. In this case, I think your package is com.java. So please try changing this arg in the command line to this: `--class com.java.JavaWordCount` . Please let me know if this works so I can put a proper answer and you can accept it if you are happy with it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. But it's still the same.              
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ​com.java.JavaWordCount"

Comment: can you share the contents of the jar file?

Comment: @EricFang, you should try to compile the jar and try to run the jar successfully. 
maybe, create a mainTest function to just print something, run `java -jar JarName.jar`. If the print statement works, then try `jar -cp JarName.jar com.java.JavaWordCount`. After that try `spark-submit`. So debug step by step.

Comment: @Yu Xiang, both commands run successfully and I post the result, but still get the error when try to spark-submit.

Comment: @Selnay , Updated.

Comment: I suggest actually making a package, but also you shouldn't "add the JAR" you just built within the actual Spark code

Comment: Are you able to spark-submit any of the built-in spark examples like SparkPi? And how are you getting "Hello" printed when that's not part of the code?

Comment: Thank you guys. I resolved this issue. But I can not locate the exact cause of this problem.